# Guice and properties files

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Does anybody have an example of how to use Google Guice to inject properties from a .properties file.  I was told Guice was able to validate that all needed properties exist when the injector starts up.

At this time I cannot find anything on the guice wiki about this.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can bind properties using `Names.bindProperties(binder(), getProperties())`, where `getProperties` returns a `Properties` object or a `Map<String, String>` (reading the properties file as a `Properties` object is up to you).

You can then inject them by name using `@Named`. If you had a properties file:

```
foo=bar
baz=true
```

You could inject the values of those properties anywhere you wanted, like this:

```
@Inject
public SomeClass(@Named("foo") String foo, @Named("baz") boolean baz) {...}
```

Guice can convert values from strings to the type being injected, such as the `boolean` above, automatically (assuming the string is an appropriate format). This works for primitive types, enums and class literals.

Comment: NB, using guice 3.0-rc2 (current latest version), this only works if you import @Named from the guice.* packages, not javax.inject.Named.

Comment: @mjg123: That should not be true... I implemented the feature that makes Guice `@Named` and `@javax.inject.Named` interchangeable myself. See the test [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/trunk/core/test/com/google/inject/name/NamedEquivalanceTest.java), which includes a test that this works with `Names.bindProperties`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I did try it - I was looking at this page because I had the same question as the OP.  I found that specifically for the case of `boolean` injection, it *did* matter which I used, although I admit I'm far from an expert in Guice.

Comment: @mjg123: I just tried it again myself using `@javax.inject.Named` and the example above (with `bindProperties`) and everything worked fine. If there is some situation where you're having to use the Guice `@Named`, could you make a small test that exposes that and report it [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/entry)?

Comment: sure, if I can reproduce it I'll post a new question.