# Is it a good Java Practice not to bind class with default constructor while injecting it in another class?

Tags: java, binding, dependency-injection, guice

I am currently working in the Guice Module. Here, I am injecting the Properties file from Java Util. The properties file constists of default constructor. So do I have to bind the properties file in my Guice Module or it will directly create the properties class with its default constructor without binding it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind it. Binding is required to map a type to its implementation. However, you can use `Names.bindProperties(Binder binder, Properties properties)`. See [Guice and properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071891/guice-and-properties-files).
You can also implement your own Provider - https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings